# How to aggregrate multiple rows with more than one columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, listagg

I have a table (named 'games') that has three columns: weather, sports and customer

```
weather sports       customer
sun     volleyball   Randy 
sun     volleyball   Lau
sun     gym          Ryan
sun     gym          Rachel
```

The table to be

```
weather sports       customer
sun     volleyball   Randy, Lau
sun     gym          Ryan, Rachel
```

I have used following LISTAGG command however it gives me error saying 'not a group by expression'

```
SELECT
    weather, sports,
    LISTAGG(customer, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sports) "Customer"
    FROM games
    GROUP BY customer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` needs to contain the *unaggregated* columns.  They define each row in the result set:

```
SELECT weather, sports,
       LISTAGG(customer, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sports) as Customers
FROM games
GROUP BY weather, sports;
```